# Is it possible to use Nutch 2.x and Apache Gora with plain filesystem as backend storage

Tags: storage, nutch, gora

Is it possible to use Nutch 2.x and Apache Gora™ with plain filesysem as backend storage?

Official site says:

> Nutch 2.x: An emerging alternative taking direct inspiration from 1.x,
>   but which differs in one key area; storage is abstracted away from any
>   specific underlying data store by using Apache Gora™ for handling
>   object to persistent mappings.

I want to use latest version of nutch (2.1 currently), but I don't want to setup complex backend with nosql or rdbms backend for storage now. I want to choose backend storage later.

I didn't find any docs for usage of filesystem as storage for Gora. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AvroStore](http://gora.apache.org/current/gora-core.html) that saves into a file (serialized with Avro).
I say this only theoretically since I never used it...